# use a passed val in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to pass a value from html and use it to find a var in my Js, so according to the value in **theId** on my html I could use the var in my js. How can I do that?

**HTML**

```
 <input id="Waist" type="checkbox" onchange="getToWork(this.id)" >Waist
```

**`<script>` tag on HTML**

```
function  getToWork(theId){
  usedCheckBox(theId);
}
```

**myJs.js**

```
  function usedCheckBox(theId){

    var temp1 = theId.name; - will be undefined
    var temp2 = Waist.name; - will work
}

var Waist = {name:"bob",age:"17"}
```

Comment: *"will be undefined"* That can't be. It should throw an error. Same for `Waist.val();`. **Strings** don't have a `val()` method. (However, there is a chance that `Waist` refers to the DOM element not the string).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, you are not using document.getElementById as below:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("Waist").addEventListener("change",function(evt){
    getToWork(this.id);
})

function getToWork(theId){
  usedCheckBox(theId);
}

function usedCheckBox(theId){
    console.log(theId);
    console.log(Waist);
    var temp1 = document.getElementById("Waist").val; // will return Waist
    var temp2 = Waist.val(); // generate error, don't know what you want
}

var Waist = "change today!"
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xLvzah8w/1/

I understood your question now and for that you should create one parent object as shown:

```
function usedCheckBox(theId){
    var temp1 = parent[theId].name; // will return bob
    console.log(temp1);
    var temp2 = parent.Waist.name; // will return bob
        console.log(temp2);
}

var parent = {
  Waist : {name:"bob",age:"17"}
}
```

**The reason why your code doesn't work is because you are trying to access property of a string. 'theId' is a string with value 'Waist' where Waist is an object so error occurs.**

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLvzah8w/2/

Comment: I need to use the value that passed to my function as it was a var in my js.file

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the onclick attribute and rather listen for the event "js side" (addEventListener/attachEvent). 
In the context of those eventhandlers, *this* generally represents the element the event listener has been attached to:

```
document.getElementById("Waist").addEventListener("change",getToWork);

function getToWork(){
    usedCheckBox(this);
}
function usedCheckBox(elem){
    var value = elem.value ;
}
```

Comment: I need to use the value that passed to my function as it was a var in my js.file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to proceed with this is:

In place of `var temp1 = theId.val();`

Use `document.getElementById(theId).value`

Comment: use `var temp1 = document.getElementById(theId).value;` and in the next line use `console.log(temp1);`  It'll show the value

Answer (score 0):

When you do: `theId.val()`, it makes sense that it's `undefined`. Calling `getToWork(this.id)` is sending a *string*, not an HTML element. Therefore calling `.val()` on a string is undefined.

If you're trying to get the text value stored in the checkbox element that was pressed, you need to change to ...

```js
function getToWork(arg) {
  console.log(document.getElementById(arg).value);
}
```

```html
<input id="Waist" type="checkbox" value="INPUT_BOX" onchange="getToWork(this.id)"> Waist
```